# No such file or directory

Tags: php, function, appwrite

In the code, I can't able to identify what's wrong with the path so that in running that function in Appwrite causes the file not found an issue

I took reference of this code https://github.com/appwrite/templates/blob/main/php/sync-with-algolia/src/utils.php

```
<?php

$staticFolder = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../static';
/**
 * Returns the contents of a file in the static folder
 * @param string $fileName
 * @return string Contents of static/{$fileName}
 */
function get_static_file(string $fileName): string
{
    global $staticFolder;
    $file = $staticFolder . '/' . $fileName;
    return file_get_contents($file);
}

/**
 * Throws an exception if any of the keys are missing from the object
 * @param array|object $obj
 * @param string[] $keys
 * @throws Exception
 */
function throw_if_missing(mixed $obj, array $keys): void
{
    $missing = [];
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if (!isset($obj[$key]) || empty($obj[$key])) {
            $missing[] = $key;
        }
    }
    if (count($missing) > 0) {
        throw new Exception('Missing required fields: ' . implode(', ', $missing));
    }
}

/**
 * Interpolates values into a template string.
 * @param string $template The template string containing placeholders like "{{key}}".
 * @param array<string, string|null> $values An associative array with keys and values to replace in the template.
 * @return string The interpolated string with placeholders replaced by corresponding values.
 */
function interpolate(string $template, array $values): string
{
    return preg_replace_callback('/{{([^}]+)}}/', function ($matches) use ($values) {
        $key = $matches[1];
        return isset($values[$key]) ? $values[$key] : '';
    }, $template);
}
```

[image: Directory Structure]

Below is the error which occurs when I ran the function in Appwrite and executed with /GET request[image][image]

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to Code/Data/Error Messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). 
Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the 
problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Don't forget the difference between physical paths and virtual paths - you're trying to open a file that is in the root _of your physical file system_, not the virtual root of your site.

Comment: can you plz elaborate more about what issue I have, also I have edited the question

Comment: The global variable $staticFolder inside the function return null

Comment: How did you debug that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Read https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths

Comment: Check the parent folder permission. I faced this type of issue and mostly time solved problem with parent folder permission.

Comment: How can I check the parent folder permission @PiyushSapariya ?

Comment: Refer this link : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13858/do-the-parent-directorys-permissions-matter-when-accessing-a-subdirectory
some one already explain perfectly and also explain how to give permission to parent folder.